Can setpci in combination with udev change USB bus assignment
On intel machine all the USB2 device are assigned to a single XHCI bus, even if they are connected to a hub attached to the USBC port. This is unfortunate if I need to passthough the corresponding PCIE address to a QEMU VM. In that cases the host will lose mouse and keyboard. Any mouse or keyboard will be going to the VM, since all of them are USB2.
Is there a way to reassign USB2 devices to a different USB bus/PCIE address, possibly using a combination of udev and setpci. I do not have a free PCIE slot for additional USB card.
I was looking for a TRUE USBC or USB3 mouse/keyboard. No able to find one. I do not want to pass the USB port of the devices that I need. The passthrough is more reliable when I pass the entire PCIE address.
